# ios: add compass to ARView

Tags: objective-c, ios, orientation, augmented-reality, compass-geolocation

I wanna add a compass to ARView in the following project: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/pARk/Listings/pARk_ARView_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011083-pARk_ARView_m-DontLinkElementID_5

I used `- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading`

But it doesnt seem to be executed .
Please Help me solve this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

See the below quote from the [Location Awareness Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/GettingHeadings/GettingHeadings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH5-SW1). Also, you might want to check your location configuration (under "Privacy" in iOS 6) in the `Settings` app to make sure your app is authorized for location operations.

According to the Guide:

> The steps for receiving heading events are as follows:
>
> 1. Create a `CLLocationManager` object.
> 2. Determine whether heading events are available by calling the `headingAvailable` class method. (In iOS 3.x and earlier, check the value of the `headingAvailable` property instead.)
> 3. Assign a `delegate` to the location manager object.
> 4. If you want true north values, start location services.
> 5. Call the `startUpdatingHeading` method to begin the delivery of heading events.